# Is it possible to make SVG equal to path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

Helo I have a problem. I am using npm package which provides pack of weather icons. The problem is the SVG box is big and it breaks positioning that is a lot of white space on website, it does not look nice. Is negative margin the way>

```
import {wiCloudy} from 'weather-icons-react'

const WeatherDataBox = () => { 
   return (
 icon=<WiCloudy size={256}  />

)}



<svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor"
    stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 30 30" 
    attr="[object Object]" size="256" height="256" width="256">
   <path>*long code*</path>
</svg>
```

Comment: can you add scale css function around this.
.scaled {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
and apply this to the icon?

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean but it still takes a lot of empty space, much bigger than path is. I mean it is now 128 height and width but path has like 80 width and height.

Comment: what is that attr for? viewBox sets it as 30 by 30, try setting width and height 30x30. svgs are supposed to scale right.

Comment: Scale breaks HTML flow. I tried other packages but all of them are same. I will keep it eh.

Comment: I modified viewBox and it works fine. Nevertheless is it good practice to hardcode? :P

Comment: Usually the svg icons I receive from our designer, have all viewBox properties set, and none of §attr="[object Object]" size="256" height="256" width="256"§, I guess this are conflicting values, probably having just one of them should be fine.

Comment: You may need to recalculate the value of the viewBox attribute. Can you edit the question and add the d attribute of the path?

Comment: It works fine for me when I changed viewBox  "5 5 20 20"

Answer (score 0):

I changed viewbox and it reduced empty background

```
let ICON_SIZE = 256
let VIEWBOX = "5 5 20 20"
<WiCloudy viewBox={VIEWBOX}  size={ICON_SIZE}  />
```